# Is there any special benefit to defending a "tall" gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes the map icon of a gym is taller than usual. Based on what I've found online, this means that the total CP in the gym is at least 8000. I've also seen it implied that this is highly desirable, for example [this tier list](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/gym-defenders-tier-list) referencing the "gym-height strat" multiple times, but none of the sources I've found have explained *why* it's so important.

Is there any benefit to gym height beyond the obvious benefit of higher total CP, like maybe additional defensive bonuses, slower CP decay, or better rewards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no direct benefits for having a tall gym: no defensive bonuses, change in CP decay, rewards etc.

There is a practical advantage in the sense that a gym being tall can offput people from attacking the gym. The higher CP means that the gym would likely be more difficult to defeat since the defenders are assumingly stronger both in terms of individual CP and motivation. Generally gyms that aren't tall either have fewer defenders, less motivation or both, making them easier targets. It's often said that the best way to defend a gym is to discourage opponents from attacking in the first place!

Comment: I think the first one who said that was Sun Tzu in The Art of War.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a tall gym and a small gym is entirely cosmetic. Gyms frequently switch between being tall and being small due to the pokémon inside losing motivation, being defeated away, being fed or being added. Sometimes even, a gym is small although it should be tall and after touching and exiting the size changes.

(And obviously tall gyms look cooler on the map.)

Comment: This is not adding any new information to the existing answer.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I don’t know but I see a difference between ‘There is a practical advantage’ and ‘The difference […] is entirely cosmetic’.

Comment: The other post is saying that the difference is entirely cosmetic, which may or may not have a psychological effect.